# How to uncheck checkbox when it reaches a certain width with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make my website responsive. Currently my checkbox remains checked when I increase the width over 640 and reduced again below it.

This is my current html code.

```
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
        <div class="hamburger">
            <label class="toggle">
                <input type="checkbox">
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <span></span>
                        <span></span>
                    </div>
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="#path">
                    </svg>
                    <svg>
                        <use xlink:href="#path">
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </label>

            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
                <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 44" id="path">
                    <path d="M22,22 L2,22 C2,11 11,2 22,2 C33,2 42,11 42,22"></path>
                </symbol>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

This is my current javascript to go along with it.(WHICH IS WORKING)

```
var toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle input')
var animate = setInterval(() => {
    toggle.checked = !toggle.checked
}, 3000)

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(animate);
})
```

I tried this code for the resizing but it didnt seem to work...

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 640px)').matches) {
        document.getElementById('toggle').checked = false;
    }
}, true);
```

I am quite new to this so I'm probably missing something blindly obvious.

Turns out on top of this ID syntax being wrong the `document.getElementById` the function path wasn't referenced properly.

Comment: There isn't any element with an id of "toggle" in your HTML.

Comment: He is toggling with class toggle

Comment: @Shahjahan where?

Comment: Sorry my bad, didn't see that inside resize function. You are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in this way

```js
var toggle = document.querySelector('.toggle input')
var animate = setInterval(() => {
    toggle.checked = !toggle.checked
}, 3000)

document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(animate);
});

function displayWindowSize(){
    var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;

    if(w > 300){
      //do Your logic here
    }
}
     
window.addEventListener("resize", displayWindowSize);
    
// Calling the function for the first time
//displayWindowSize();
```

```html
<div class="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
<div class="hamburger">
    <label class="toggle">
        <input type="checkbox">
        <div>
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </div>
            <svg>
                <use xlink:href="#path">
            </svg>
            <svg>
                <use xlink:href="#path">
            </svg>
        </div>
    </label>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">
        <symbol xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 44 44" id="path">
            <path d="M22,22 L2,22 C2,11 11,2 22,2 C33,2 42,11 42,22"></path>
        </symbol>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the logic I put in just what was in my IF statement before? If so it didnt want to work?

Comment: Yes! That's it! Actually you are using `id` to toggle inside your resize segment but your code doesn't have any `id` named `toggle`

Comment: document.querySelector(".toggle input").checked = false; Does that what Gilbert said work?

Comment: Or do i need to create a toggle ID?

Comment: You can do it with querySelector, don't need to create and Id for that

Comment: Why is there commented out stuff at the end of your code?

Comment: That was for for on load call, When page load it'll check for initial size of viewport, then it'll trigger by resizing

Comment: Ah okay I see. Thank you so much for the help! Turns out i wasn't referencing the js file correctly in the html file aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.innerWidth` instead.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 640) {
        // Your current code... except there isn't an element of this id
        document.getElementById('toggle').checked = false;

        // Did you mean this?
        document.querySelector(".toggle input").checked = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: @Joelad you probably want to delete the line that starts with `document.getElementById...`

Comment: Also, what error message are you getting in the console?

Comment: I did delete that line yeah

Comment: @Joelad Create a JSFiddle and put your code in it. Then put the link to the fiddle on here and we will be able to fix it together.

Comment: Got it to work on Fiddle so wondered why it wasnt working on my actual project